# Jquery draggables: Removing an element changes position of other dropped elements

Tags: jquery, position, element, draggable

When elements are placed / dropped (by dragging from one DIV to another) and then removing one in the dropped DIV, some of them are changing the position.

Here is a test scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/TcYHW/8/

And the main code:

```
<div id="dropwin"></div>
<div id="dragables">
    <div id="d1" class="d"></div>
    <div id="d2" class="d"></div>
    <div id="d3" class="d"></div>
    <div id="d4" class="d"></div>
</div>


$(".d").draggable({
        containment: '#dropwin',
        stack: '#dragables div',
        cursor: 'move',
      });
```

How can I avoid this?

I found, that the elements are placed in relative position to the starting position. How can I make them stick at the dropped position even if some are removed?

I found two near similar questions, but without an satisfying answer:

[Remove in Jquery divs with draggables and resizables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514337/remove-in-jquery-divs-with-draggables-and-resizables)

[jQuery draggable removing without changing position of other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114638/jquery-draggable-removing-without-changing-position-of-other-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your elements to be positioned `absolute`. Then the deleted boxes won't affect the flow of the other elements.

You could just use css to position them `absolute`:

```
.d { 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But then you would have to manually place each box.  The trick is to leave them positioned `static` (or `relative` after `.draggable()` gets done) and then use javascript to set their positions and set them to `absolute` positioning:

```
$('.d').each(function() {
    var top = $(this).position().top + 'px';
    var left = $(this).position().left + 'px';
    $(this).css({top: top, left: left});
}).css({position: 'absolute'});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/5S92K/

Comment: Thank you, your solution looks like that what i need, but only if the "dropwin" is (static) on the top left corner. If you try this http://jsfiddle.net/BillyG/5S92K/2/ where the DIV is centered and change the browser window size horizontally, the dropped draggables don't stay fixed, they move. The positioning have to be absolute in relation to the dropwin-box. A hint, how to resolve this?

Comment: `#dropwin` and `#dragables` need to have `position: relative` for absolute positioning to do the right thing.  http://jsfiddle.net/5S92K/3/

Comment: Thank you, it solves it the best way so far. I prefer your solution because it does not need extra tags around the draggables as Kaushtuvs' solution does.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some edits in your jsFiddle demo and it seemed to be working

My Edits:

```
<div id="dropwin"></div>
<div id="dragables">
<div class="outer"><div id="d1" class="d"></div></div>
<div class="outer"><div id="d2" class="d"></div></div>
<div class="outer"><div id="d3" class="d"></div></div>
<div class="outer"><div id="d4" class="d"></div></div>
</div>
<button id="b1">Remove d1</button>
<button id="b2">Remove d2</button>
<button id="b3">Remove d3</button>
<button id="b4">Remove d4</button>
```

And in css:

```
#dropwin { width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #f00;}
#dragables { width: 300px; height: 70px; border: 1px solid #00f; }
.d { width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block; }
#d1 { background: #f00; position:absolute; }
#d2 { background: #ff0; position:absolute; }
#d3 { background: #f0f; position:absolute; }
#d4 { background: #0ff; position:absolute; }
.outer{ margin:1px 2px 0 0; float:left; width:60px;}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried you solution here http://jsfiddle.net/BillyG/TcYHW/9/ and it looks good, even if the "dropwin" is centered. I will implement this in my application and see if it solves the problem. But why have you added this margins on top and right of the outer-class?

Comment: Forgot to add the position:absolute on #d1-#d4 
http://jsfiddle.net/BillyG/TcYHW/10/

Comment: Without the margin the divs will collapse into one another initially. What I mean is the four div will be on top of one another when the code first loads. Glad its working now. can you accept the answer then : ) cheers.